# Any two ordered fields with the least upper bound property are order isomorphic.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove this. I know that I have to find a bijection between the two fields (let's say $A$ and $B$) that have the following properties:

Let $f: A \to B$ be a bijection.

$$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$$
$$f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$$
$$x < y \in A\therefore f(x) < f(y) \in B$$

I have a problem just by coming up with the bijection, since this is between any two arbitrary fields. I am just looking for hints, thanks!

Comment: First show each field contains a copy of the rationals.

Comment: @GEdgar But why would that be the case?

Comment: Have you heard of "characteristic zero"?

Comment: @GEdgar No. I am using Tools of the Trade by Sally. I don;t really like this book.

Answer (score 2):

Do it in stages.  First you have to show that $0 \to 0, 1 \to 1$.  Then you can show that the rationals map properly.  Then use the least upper bound property to map the reals properly.

Comment: By using Dedekind cuts on the rationals. And show that the rationals together with the cuts is the whole field: If not then there exists  $x>0$ with $x$ less than every positive rational. But then $\{y>0:\forall q\in \mathbb Q^+\;(y<q)\}$ would be a non-empty bounded set with no lub.